# Delete an isolated storage file

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I know this may sound extremely nooby, so sorry in advance but I am learning and I have spent nearly 2 hours trying to find out how to do this now with no result...

I'm wondering how I would go about deleting a specific file from isolated storage in windows phone 7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply call [`IsolatedStorageFile.DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletefile.aspx).

For example:

```
IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
storage.DeleteFile("backup.bak");
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and its working but its throwing exceptions:

System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException

Comment: One thing to remember is that the WP7 emulator throws out Isolated Storage when it's closed. So if you've created the file, closed the emulator and try to delete on next run you'll catch an exception.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`IsolatedStorageFile.DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletefile.aspx).

```
using(var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    store.DeleteFile("path.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// you should add here try / catch blocks

using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
store.DeleteFile("Your file Name string");
}
```

You can check the class here:
[MSDN IsolatedStorageFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the existing answers: remember to catch an [IsolatedStorageException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorageexception.aspx) and not an IOException as you might be use to.