# File stay in isolatedstorage even i delete it

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

In my app i am able to record 3 times my voice and also listen to recorded sounds . and after listening ,by another function i remove them from isolatedstorage . but the problem is , the last sound that i listened to , stay in isolatedstorage and remove method of isolatedstorage is not able to delete the last playback. and for next time when i want to record sound i will get error . how can i solve this problem ?

Error :

[image]

code for recording sound :

```
        private void SaveTempAudio(MemoryStream buffer)
    {

        using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            var bytes = buffer.GetWavAsByteArray(_recorder.SampleRate);
            var tempFileName = "tempwave_" + _counter +".wav" ;

            using (var audioStream = isoStore.CreateFile(tempFileName))
            {
                audioStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                _counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

code for playback and listen to recorded sound ;

```
        private void PlayBackSound( string fileName)
    {

        using (var isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!isoStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                return;

            using (var fileStream = isoStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                SoundPlayer.SetSource(fileStream);
                SoundPlayer.Play();

            }
        }
    }
```

for removing file i use :

```
             using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            isoStore.Remove();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [IsolatedStorageFile.DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletefile.aspx) as shown here [Delete an isolated storage file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199091/delete-an-isolated-storage-file)

Comment: are you giving correct path ? check for it. if path is correct then above should work Properly

Comment: yes the path is correct . when i don't listen to recorded sound , i have no problem , and also i can able to remove all of them , but if i listen to them , the last file (it does not matter which one), i will get an error ...

Comment: may be that last played refrence is not released so it couldnt delete referenced file

Comment: Yes i think you are right , but how can i release that file ?

Comment: When i do something like this : SoundPlayer.Source= null;   at the end of playback function , every thing goes well without any exception , but i can not able to listen to recorded sound

Answer (score 0):

What i did as a solution to release resources from mediaEelemnt is this code . and now i am able to remove all the recorded sounds, you just need to handle MediaEnded event of mediaelement and pass null to source property :

```
void SoundPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      SoundPlayer.Source = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all streams after using them. May be its due to the stream being open.